# button in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have `listview` customized by `simplecursoradapter` .in each row i have the text and button

I want to click to both the button and list item , but i only click to button 
 so what i should do to to `onclicklistener` them.

Comment: I don't think that the `ListView` will receive a click event if the button is being pushed - you could always just call the `onClickListener` event of the `ListView` from the button's `onClickListener`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to handle this inside the `getView()` or `bindView()` method of your custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Have a look at the given code snippet:

```
public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent)
{
        if (inView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_file, null); 
        }
        Button btn = (Button) inView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() // Click event on button
        {               
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // do what you want when click on button here
            }
        }               
        return inView;
}
```

Comment: Barely this solution won't work, since the Button will take the focus to itself, and the item will stop being tappable. The button put in a row should also be non-focusable (android:focusable="false" in XML layout).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source for the alarm clock app, you will see this functionality in a custom layout that is used for the list item

```
/**
 * Special class to to allow the parent to be pressed without being pressed
 * itself. This way the time in the alarm list can be pressed without changing
 * the background of the indicator.
 */
public class DontPressWithParentLayout extends RelativeLayout {

public DontPressWithParentLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    // If the parent is pressed, do not set to pressed.
    if (pressed && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
        return;
    }
    super.setPressed(pressed);
}
}
```

Then they set the `clickHandlers` for both the list item and the button in the adapter they use.

Answer (score -1):

For listview to be clickable you can use onItemClickListener

Comment: The question is about how to track an item and button-that-is-in-the-item click-s at the same time.